# memory_limit return different values in php5-cli and browser

Tags: php-ini, php

I am writing a script that requires me to get all php configuration. But I stumble an issue and inconsistencies when I run the `ini_get_all()` in the browser and using `php5-cli`. Here is my code snippet:

```
$confiq = ini_get_all();
echo $config['memory_limit']['local_value'];
```

It return 128M when I run using browsers, but it return -1 when I run using php5-cli from the command line

EDIT: It turned out they are using two different php.ini files. I checked the cli .ini with `php --ini` command. Now I need to figure out how to change the location for .ini file for cli

EDIT: For the easy hack, I created symbolic links to the apache2 php.ini to make sure both using the same php.ini.

Comment: check if both are using same ini file

Comment: easiest. just remove (backup) the cli ini and put a symbolic link to the ini you require.

Comment: @bansi: Yeah. I believe it will work that way. Not sure best practice or not though. Not really familiar with php.

Comment: not sure why you want this. you can use also CURL to get output of the real PHP url in your script. by that way you can altogether avoid cli

Comment: @bansi: When I am doing right now is I am checking my two servers have same configuration. So right now I wrote a script that will CURL-ing my other server and get my current configuration by using function call with CLI.

Comment: then you can CURL to the local server also instead of cli, I would suggest that because it is what the exact config your web server will be using.

Comment: Yes. I gave up figuring out to sync the cli and apache. That is what I did now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different php.ini files.

`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`  for web and  `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`   for command line.

You need to edit corresponding ini file according to the context. If you need the same ini value in both cli and web, obviously you need to edit both. Also don't forget to restart apache (`service apache2 restart`) after editing ini files to see the changes.

Comment: i think `Systemd` has taken over `SysVinit` +1 for solving tha actual problem